# How to process many form input fields using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a survey application, and I have a form that can have potentially hundreds of input fields.  How would I write the controller to process this form?  I can't specify each input as a parameter for the controller, that would be unrealistic.

I found out about the MVCToolkit, and the UpdateFrom() method, but is this the right way to go?  If so, how would I install the MVCToolkit in my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually way simpler than that.  You just need to use an object called `FormCollection`.

```
public ActionResult MyFormUpdate (int id, FormCollection form) {
    // do form updates
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can accept collections as parameters in Action as well.

```
public ActionResult TheAction (string[] answers) {

}
```

Html :

```
<input type="text" name="answers[0]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="answers[1]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="answers[2]" value="" />
<!--and so on -->
```

The default model binder will automatically populate the answers array in your action with the values entered in the form.